# 16.04 Quicklists SSHFS Mount Problem

Tags: mount, 16.04, launcher, quicklists, sshfs

I have a launcher that looks like this...

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Mount Options
Comment=Mount Utility (Unmount by Default)
Exec=sh -c "sudo umount /media/*"
Icon=/usr/share/icons/nouveGnomeGray/48x48/places/gtk-network.png
Terminal=true
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true

Actions=SSH Dev-Derek;Mount Dev-Derek;

[Desktop Action SSH Dev-Derek]
Name=SSH Dev-Derek
Exec=terminator -e "ssh user@place.com"
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Mount Dev-Derek]
Name=Mount Dev-Derek
Exec=terminator -e "sshfs user@place.com:/var /media/myfolder/"
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

The left click unmount works.
The ssh command works.
The SSHFS command allows me to input my creds but doesn't mount the share.

I can mount fine if I open a terminal and use the command... but thats what Quicklists is for.

```
~$ sshfs user@place.com:/var /media/myfolder/
```

I've tried using:

```
Exec=sh -c "sshfs user@place.com:/var /media/myfolder/"
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "sshfs user@place.com:/var /media/myfolder/"
```

Answer (score 0):

For one reason or another I could not get the terminal to allow me to enter a password and make the mount stick.

I solved this by storing my key on the target server.

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id user@server.com
```